# php compare float numbers with input field value

Tags: php, comparison, floating-point, concrete5

I have a form in which users can enter floating point values. I post these values to a php script and i compare if the numbers the users entered are between some values. If i post an integer the comparison returns true no matter if the number exceeded the boundaries. If i entere a floating point number the comparison fails no matter if the number is within the boundaries. I am not stupid, i've done floating point comparisons in c++ and i know how to do an if( float1 >= float2) return false...

here is my code:

```
//loading the helper
$val = Loader::helper('synerciel_form','synerciel_client');
//adding the fields to the inputs array for validation
$val->between('isolation_des_murs_peripheriques', 2.8, null, t($between.'Isolation des murs 
p&egrave;riph&egrave;riques'), true, false);
```

//helper class

```
class SynercielFormHelper extends ValidationFormHelper {
    const VALID_BETWEEN = 7;
    const VALID_FLOAT = 7;
    private $min;
    private $max;
    private $includeLow;
    private $includeHigh;

 public function between($field, $min, $max, $errorMsg, $includeLow = true, $includeHigh = true) {
        $const = SynercielFormHelper::VALID_BETWEEN;
        $this->min = $min;
        $this->max = $max;
        $this->includeLow = $includeLow;
        $this->includeHigh = $includeHigh;

        $this->addRequired($field, $errorMsg, $const);
    }
   ...
   public function test() {

    $between = new ValidationNumbersBetweenHelper();
    if (!$between->between($this->data[$field], $this->min, $this->max, $this->includeLow, $this->includeHigh)) {
                        $this->fieldsInvalid[] = $f;
}

}
```

My validation method (i believe here is the tricky part)

```
class ValidationNumbersBetweenHelper {

    public function between($data, $min = null, $max = null, $includeLow = true, $includeHigh = true) {

        if ($min && $includeLow) {
            if (!($data >= $min))
                return false;
        } else if ($min) {
            if (!($data > $min))
                return false;
        }
        if ($max && $includeHigh) {
            if (!($data <= $max))
                return false;
        } else if ($max) {
            if (!($data < $max))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: the 2 previous code snippets have been added just so you can understand where i am storing the vars and the overall flow of the calls...i believe the last code snipped is the one that you should be interested in

Answer (score 0):

Check the warning message http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

You can use BC Math Functions http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php

```
$status = bccomp($left, $right);
if ($status == 0) {
    echo 'equal';
} else if ($status > 0) {
    echo 'left bigger than right';
} else {
   echo 'right bigger than left';
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try isolating the troublesome code. Put your validation function into a stand-alone PHP file and test it there. Try checking `$max` and `$min` for `!== null` as `0` is also `false`. You could reverse the logic and remove all the `!`s. (e.g. change `>=` to `<`) so instead of "not greater than or equal to" you can have "less than"